# How to remove appended 3rd party script Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am loading/appending a 3rd party CDN script (using JQuery) on Component load. The Script is successfully appended into the DOM. But, unfortunately, if I go to other routes and come back to this component, the script is not executing anymore. Anyone has any clue how to solve this or what's possibly going wrong? Or how can I remove this Script everytime when I come to this route and load the Script again?

This is a Snippet of how I am appending the Script to DOM

```
  loadScript(name: string) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (!this.scripts[name].loaded) {
    //load script
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.id = this.scripts[name];
    script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
    script.charset = "UTF-8";
    if (script.readyState) {
      //IE
      script.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (
          script.readyState === "loaded" ||
          script.readyState === "complete"
        ) {
          script.onreadystatechange = null;
          this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
          resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Loaded" });
        }
      };
    } else {
      //Others
      script.onload = () => {
        this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
        resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Loaded" });
      };
    }
    script.onerror = (error: any) =>
      resolve({ script: name, loaded: false, status: "Loaded" });
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  } else {
    resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Already Loaded" });
  }
});
```

}
}

Comment: Can you please also share how are you invoking the loadScript method in your component?

Comment: Hi @Raj Invoking the LoadScript on Component's OnInit

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit hard to figure out the major reason to encounter this issue, but some ideas would be helpful to fix the problem.

**Remove script**

You can remove the script on `ngOnDestroy()` event of the component.

**Setting `async` to false**

As I know, by default, `async` attribute for `script` tags is true. So, to load script it would make problems. You could set this attribute like this:

```
//load script
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.id = this.scripts[name];
script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
script.charset = "UTF-8";
script.async = false; // set async
```

**Caching in Angular**

Last but not least, caching in SPA would make problem. As far as I'm concerned `jQuery` sets caching JS to true. Make sure it makes no problem in your code.

I guess your issue is related to these items. You could check them step by step. I hope I could help you.